# Is this "confession question" back on-topic?

Tags: discussion

@chathan asked a [question about confession](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32769/does-the-catholic-church-really-believe-that-god-really-forgive-by-confession) recently that was marked off-topic as a Truth Question. @chathan edited the question title to focus on Catholicism, and subsequently I edited the question body and added the [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) tag to go along with the apparent intended focus.

Given the edits, is it OK to be taken off hold?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, **yes**, and I've voted for reopening.

Comment: I did as well..